# Twitter file Theme Check Warnings

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have created a WordPress Theme. After Integrating Recent Tweets in my theme, I have checked with the theme file in themeforest check plugin. In that we got two warnings.

```
WARNING: curl_init was found in the file twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php possible file operations. Line 195: $ci = curl_init();

WARNING: curl_exec was found in the file twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php possible file operations. Line 221: $response = curl_exec($ci);
```

Please help me solve these warning errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this warning is not caused by php. This warning is set by http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/. Also read: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/timthumb-warning-issue

The latest update of the plugin was 2012-12-11, nearly one year ago. Althought the plugin works on version 3.7.1 it won't be sure all check are uptodate.